# The evaluation of the integration of absolute value of second derivative $f''(x)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be a function  on $[0, C]$ with continuous second derivative.  Suppose $M=\max_{x\in [0,C]}f(x)$  and $m=\min_{x\in [0,C]}f(x)$, then $M-m\leq C\int_{0}^{C}|f''(x)|dx$.

My thought:    Since $C\int_{0}^{C}f''(x)dx\leq
 C\int_{0}^{C}|f^{''}(x)|dx$, we have $C(f'(C)–f'(0))\leq C\int_{0}^{C}|f''(x)|dx$, how to check that $M-m\leq C(f'(C)–f'(0))$?

Comment: Do not use superscrpits for primes and double primes. They are already typeset correctly without them. And use '' for a double prime, not ".

Comment: If $C=1$ and $f(x)=x$, then $M-m \leq T\int_{0}^{T}|f^{''}(x)|dx$ is false.

Comment: @Fred,sorry, it was a typo. I have reedited it.

Comment: But it's still false : if $f(x) = x$ then $f''(x) = 0$, so the RHS will always be $0$ and the LHS will be bigger than $0$ if $C>0$.

Comment: If $M=\max_{x\in (0,C)}f(x)$ and $m=\min_{x\in (0,C)}f(x)$, is the above conclusion correct?